# Setting lifetime manager for registrations done using UnityConfiguration scanner

Tags: configuration, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 application and am using Unity for IOC. I am using Unity.MVC4 and UnityConfiguration Nuget packages to help with the registration.

I need to automatically register a load of interfaces and their related types to the Unity container. To do this I created a dummy interface; IDependencyInjectionScanner that all my real interfaces inherit from. Below is the code showing that.

```
public interface IDependencyInjectionScanner
{

}

public interface IChair : IDependencyInjectionScanner
{
    NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
}

public class Chair : IChair
{
    public NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
}

public interface ITable : IDependencyInjectionScanner
{
    NumberOfChairs { get; set; }
}

public class Table : ITable
{
    public NumberOfChairs { get; set; }
}
```

I then used UnityConfiguration to bind the registrations using the scanner. I have get the interfaces being correctly resolved in the controller. Below is the code that shows how I did the binding.

```
Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.AssembliesInDirectory(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin"));
            scan.With<FirstInterfaceConvention>();
            scan.Include(x => (x.GetInterface(typeof(IDependencyInjectionScanner).Name) != null));
            scan.ForRegistries();
        });
```

The problem is that I want to register all the types found by the scanner using the hierarchical lifetime manager but can figure out how to do this. The GitHub page for UnityConfiguration https://github.com/thedersen/UnityConfiguration states that this could be achieved by the code below:

```
Configure<IChair>().AsHierarchicalControlled();
```

However I if I have to do that for each of the interfaces bound by the scanner then the scanner is of no use as I may as well do:

```
Register<IChair, Chair>().AsHierarchicalControlled();
```

Can someone assist me with finding a solution to this please.

Comment: I would encourage you to look at Unity 3.0 and the built-in [Registration by Convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec23) feature.  This would solve your problem, but using a completely different approach which might not be possible for you.

Comment: I did have a look at that before but couldnt get it to work i will revisit it at somepoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer to your question using UnityConfiguration.  You can create a custom convention to configure the lifetime.  Just be careful because it looks like the calls within the Scan() method are order dependent.

```
public class HierarchicalLifetimeConvention : IAssemblyScannerConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, IUnityRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.Configure(type).AsHierarchicalControlled();
    }
}
```

and then add that to your Scan() call...

```
Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.AssembliesInDirectory(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin"));
        scan.With<FirstInterfaceConvention>();
        scan.With<HierarchicalLifetimeConvention>(); //<-- New convention
        scan.Include(x => (x.GetInterface(typeof(IDependencyInjectionScanner).Name) != null));
        scan.ForRegistries();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @TylerOhlsen I used the built-in Registration by Convention feature of Unity 3.0.  I have got it to add the registration mappings and they are using the hierarchical lifetime manager. below is the code for that

```
container.RegisterTypes(
      AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(
        t => t.GetInterface(typeof(IDependencyInjectionScanner).Name) != null),
      WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
      WithName.Default,
      WithLifetime.Hierarchical);
```

There is one thing that is disturbing me; when I look at the registrations I have 4 (based on the example code above). 2 type mappings for the Chair type and 2 type mappings for the Table type.

Can anyone shed any light on why this is, as I was only expecting two mappings.

Comment: Judging by the [source](https://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Unity/Unity/Src/RegistrationByConvention/UnityContainerRegistrationByConventionExtensions.cs), this is by design.  It registers each type with all the types that are configured with the WithMappings.* func and also a special registration of the type by itself with the specified lifetime and injection members.  (i.e. once for a mapping of the type to its interface(s) and once for a mapping of the type to itself)